# Summarise data with R - other than n counts

Tags: r, aggregation

I've got donor segments

1. Donors aged 34 and younger, vs. donors aged 35 and older
2. Donors with a high frequency of donations vs. donors with a low frequency of donations

Every row in my data frame represents a donor. Some of these donors are still active, some are lapsed.

How can I display a 2x2 table of the proportion of donors who are lapsed ?

Something like :

```
table(age,frequency)
```

However instead of displaying the counts, It would display the proportion of donors who are lapsed.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Can you try the following?

```
prop.table(table(age, frequency), margin=1) 

prop.table(table(age, frequency), margin=2)
```

where margin = 1 computes row proportions and margin = 2 computes column proportions.  (Double-check the results to make sure you are computing the intended proportions.)

Here, frequency would be the variable which keeps track of donors who are lapsed or not lapsed. So you might need a margin = 2 for your specific situation, presuming you are interested in proportion of lapsed donors separately for each age category.

If you just care about proportion of lapsed donors regardless of age category, do something like table(frequency)/sum(table(frequency)).

Comment: Thanks for your answer Isabella! However, this only allows me to display the lapsed proportion for one of my axes (age). Frequency does not refer to whether a donor is lapsed or still active; this is a separate variable showing the frequency of donations.

Comment: Do you need to compute the frquency of the lapsed donor for each age by frequency of donation combination? Not clear what you are after - clarifications would be helpful.

Comment: Frequency is ambiguous here. I prefer to talk about the proportion of lapsed donor for every age and frequency of donation. Hence a 2x2 table where one axis would be age, the other would be frequency of donation. The data in the table would be the proportion of lapsed donors.

Comment: Can you provide some mock data which includes the three variables you are interested in?